# Is there a FREE file manager that fully supports Tortoise SVN (including the SVN details columns) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, explorer

Or alternatively, is there some other SVN client that has explorer ease of use but also supports the SVN details columns that are no longer available in Vista/Windows7?

I've looked briefly at things like Explorer++, FreeCommander, Xplorer2 lite but none seem to have such support.

I just want a quick, easy and free solution to the missing columns that have proved so useful when ordering the file list to see what's been added/modified etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/index.htm): it allows for [defining custom columns](http://www.freecommander.com/fc_guide_granny_DisplayElementsSavingSetups_en.htm).

(Not sure if that will support SVN informations, but the alternative, [xplorer<sup>2</sup>](http://www.zabkat.com/), which supports SVN, isn't free)

---

5 years later (2016), [Andrew Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520691/andrew-jens) confirms [in the comments below:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677770/is-there-a-free-file-manager-that-fully-supports-tortoise-svn-including-the-svn/6677818?noredirect=1#comment61545136_6677818)

> I'm very new to FreeCommander (Build 716) but I can confirm that **it does show the SVN folder icons for all items within the currently-selected folder** (i.e. the right-hand pane of the traditional Windows Explorer window).
>
> What it doesn't seem to do is show the SVN icons in the folder tree view (i.e. the left-hand pane of the traditional Windows Explorer window).
>
> This observation is based on the free 32-bit version.

He adds (again May 2016):

> I just bought the 64-bit "donor" version of FreeCommander (Build 720).
> When it comes to SVN icon display, I can confirm that it appears to function exactly the same as the 32-bit free version ... i.e. the folders in the folder tree-view do not show the SVN icons but the files and folders (in the right pane) for a selected folder do show the SVN icons.

Comment: As I mentioned I'd had a look at that and it does appear to give you some column profile customization but sadly the available columns you can see in each profile seems far less that the default explorer and also doesn't include the SVN properties. Unless I missed something...

Comment: I'm very new to FreeCommander (Build 716) but I can confirm that it does show the SVN folder icons for all items within the currently-selected folder (i.e. the right-hand pane of the traditional Windows Explorer window). What it doesn't seem to do is show the SVN icons in the folder tree view (i.e. the left-hand pane of the traditional Windows Explorer window). This observation is based on the free 32-bit version.

Comment: @AndrewJens Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I just bought the 64-bit "donor" version of FreeCommander (Build 720). When it comes to SVN icon display, I can confirm that it appears to function exactly the same as the 32-bit free version ... i.e. the folders in the folder tree-view **do not** show the SVN icons but the files and folders (in the right pane) for a selected folder **do** show the SVN icons.

Comment: @AndrewJens That is god to know, and again included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a whole bunch of these and the only (free) one I've found that supports Tortoise columns is [Cubic Explorer](http://www.cubicreality.com/ce/download/). I've only tried it on WinXP with TortoiseCVS so your results may vary.

Comment: Sadly this is still not showing the columns. I believe the underlying issue is with the OS so not sure this is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment elsewhere on this page about **FreeCommander** (which does have some support for SVN icons), but I can also confirm that **Nomad.NET** (http://www.nomad-net.info/) shows the SVN icons.

Cheers,
Andrew.

PS. I found Nomad.NET a little buggy under Windows 10 64-bit so I swapped over to FreeCommander (which so far is stable).

PPS. I can also confirm that **Xplorer2** shows the SVN icons.